# How to solve htaccess url problems

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a new member in stackoverflow and beginner for php. I started one sample blog project. It works fine, but I want to change url for seo friendly. Can any one help me please? How to write htaccess code for this blog.

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post");
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Post
</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Post List</h1>
<ul>
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>
<li><a href="post.php?pid=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></li>
<?php }?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
include("db.php");
if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $id = $_GET['pid'];
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=".$id); 
}
if($qry === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>
View Post
</title>
<style>
body{
    background-color: #c9c9c9;

}
h1, .para{
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding:10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
?>
<h1><?php echo $row1['title']; ?> </h1>
<p class="para"><?php echo $row1['desc']; ?></p>
<?php }?>

</body>
</html>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+) post.php?pid=$1 [NC]

</IfModule>
```

When i'm running this code, url shows like this:

```
http://localhost/blog/post.php?pid=1
```

I want to display url like this

```
http://localhost/blog/post/1
```

Solution is executed successfully, but css styles not working. Css styles placed in css folder

Comment: please stop using `mysql_*` as it is depracted and will be removed. Instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess is used to parse the url, its not to generate the URL. You need to rewrite line

```
<li><a href="post.php?pid=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="/blog/post/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></li>
```

and your .htaccess will work

Answer (score 0):

try this in htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and you can use a bootsrap class

```
class bootstrap {
    function __construct() {
        $url=isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
        $url=rtrim($url,'/');
        $url = explode('/',$url );
        //print_r($url);
        if(empty($url[0])) {
            require 'controllers/index.php';
            $controller = new index();
            return false;
        }
        echo $url .'<br>';
        $file = 'controllers/' .$url[0]. '.php';
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
        }
        else {
            require 'controllers/error.php';
            $controller = new error();
            return false;
        }

        $controller = new $url[0];
        if(isset($url[2])) {
            $controller ->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
        }
        else {
                if(isset($url[1])) {
                $controller ->{$url[1]}();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ post.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ post.php?pid=$1
```